NFA for $L = \{\sigma_1 u \sigma_2 v \sigma_3 \mid (\sigma_1, \sigma_2, \sigma_3 \in \Sigma, u, v \in \Sigma^*, |u| = |v|) and ...$
The question asks to write a NFA for the following language $L$ above $\Sigma = \left \{0,1  \right \}$.
$L = \{\sigma_1 u \sigma_2 v \sigma_3 \mid (\sigma_1, \sigma_2, \sigma_3 \in \Sigma, u, v \in \Sigma^*, |u| = |v|) \text{ and } (\sigma_1 = \sigma_2 \text{ or } \sigma_3 = \sigma_2 \text{ but not both})\}$
The NFA must contain at the most 7 states.
To be honest, I spent a lot of time with the pumping lemma in order to disprove the claim that the $L$ is regular but it didn't work.
I came up to the conclusion that a word $w \in L$ must hold that $|w| = 2n +3 : n \in \mathbb{N}\cup\left \{ 0 \right \}$ and it led me to the following NFA:

This NFA doesn't cover the cases where $\sigma_1 = \sigma_2 = 0 , \sigma_3 = 1$ and $\sigma_1 = 0 , \sigma_2 = \sigma_3 = 1$.
The constrain of the 7 states prevents me from thinking furthermore.
The question wasn't designed to implement Myhill–Nerode theorem to come up with the solution.
I would like to know what can be added to the NFA I draw, or perhaps I'm not even in the right direction.

Another issue that I can observe is that your NFA does not require $|u|=|v|$, but that $|u|=2x$ and $|y|=2y$ for some $x,y \in \mathbb{N} \cup {0}$ (i.e. that each string contains an even number of characters).

It is indeed regular. Here, your language is basically $1(0+1)^{2m+1}0 + 0(0+1)^{2m+1}1$ for all integers $m \ge 0$. We are basically fixing $\sigma_1 \ne \sigma_3$, and then let $|u\sigma_2v|$ be an odd cycle. This will automatically ensure the rest of the constraints are met. This is easily realizable by a NFA with 8 states, as shown below.
PS: I hope this simplification might lead to your required 7 state solution, which I cannot visualize at this moment.

Your automaton recognizes $011111$ which is not in the language: using three states for a loop will recognize words like $01^{3m+1}1$, not $01^{2m+1}1$.

Sorry my mistake, I am updating the answer

Stings like 011111 are not possible. All accepted strings are of odd length, and they start and end with different symbols.

Now you just need to delete $q_3$ and $q_6$ and put the corresponding transitions from $q_2$ and $q_5$!

@codeR Thank you very much. I also can't visualize 7 states but what you came with is very useful !!

@Nathaniel Hello! I'm not sure that "delete $q_3$ and $q_6$ and put the corresponding transitions from $q_2$ and $q_5$ " will work. In the automaton you are suggesting, you can get the word $01111$ from the path $q_0  ->  q_1  -> q_2  ->  q_1  ->  q_2 ->  q_f$  which is not in  $L$

@Daniel $01111$ is in $L$, with $u=v=1$ and $\sigma_1 = 0$, $\sigma_2=\sigma_3 = 1$.

@Nathaniel you are right, my bad, I got confused with something else. Let's consider $w=011011$ in the automaton you are suggesting. $w$ can be obtained from the path $q_0 -> q_1 -> q_2 -> q_1 -> q_2 -> q_1 -> q_2 -> q_f$ which (If I didn't mess up again) is not in $L$

The path you described has $7$ transitions for a word with $6$ letters.

@Nathaniel you won :) Is it right to say that the automaton you provided accept words $w \in \Sigma : |w| = 2 + 2n $ with appropriate suffix and prefix (the condition about $\sigma _i : i=1,2,3$) ?

@Nathaniel, I think you are right $q_2$ and $q_3$ can be merged; the same goes for the other pair. This will result into a DFA with only 6 states :)
